# Mongo $lookup nested array 3 levels deep using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this inside `outsideServices` model:

```
name: String,
salary: Number,
services: [
      {
        category: {
          ref: 'ServiceCategories',
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
        },
        types: [
          {
            ref: 'ServiceType',
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I have this inside `incidents` model:

```
  outsideServices: {
      ref: 'OutsideService',
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
    }
```

so when requesting `incidents` from api the response would be like:

```
[
  {
    category: '5cf655135a1b72106777c238',
    types: ['5cf655a85a1b72106777c239']
  },
  {
    category: '5cf656525a1b72106777c23b',
    types: ['5cf656835a1b72106777c23c']
  }
];
```

How it's possible to lookup both `categories` and `types` ref and keep the structure above in my response?

Here's what I've tried so far but I can't get the desired results:

```
aggregate.lookup({
      from: 'outsideservices',
      let: { serviceId: '$outsideServices' },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$serviceId'] } } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'servicecategories',
            let: { services: '$services.category' },
            pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $in: ['$_id', '$$services'] } } }],
            as: 'category'
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'servicetypes',
            let: { services: '$services.types' },
            pipeline: [
              { $match: { $expr: { $in: ['$_id', '$$services'] } } }
            ],
            as: 'types'
          }
        }
      ],
      as: 'outsideService'
    });
```

The wanted result/outcome is like the response above but with populated documents and not `ObjectId`s

MongoDB version `4.0.10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation. Use $unwind to deconstruct the array followed by $lookup to pull in the categories and types and finally $group to go back to original structure.

```
{
  "from":"outsideservices",
  "let":{"serviceId":"$outsideServices"},
  "pipeline":[
    {"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$_id","$$serviceId"]}}},
    {"$unwind":"$services"},
    {"$lookup":{
    "from":"servicecategories",
    "localField":"services.category",
    "foreignField":"_id",
    "as":"services.category"
    }},
    {"$lookup":{
    "from":"servicetypes",
    "localField":"services.types",
    "foreignField":"_id",
    "as":"services.types"
    }},
    {"$group":{
    "_id":null,
    "services":{"$push":"$services"}
    }}
  ],
  "as":"outsideService"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if I want to keep the entire document and not only `{_id: null, services: [...] ` in the response what do I have to do? I tried `{
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            services: { $push: '$services' },
            doc: { $first: '$$ROOT' }
          }
        },
        {
          $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$doc' }
        }`but this will result in only one service to be returned (as it should because of `$first`).

Comment: You are welcome. Insert `{$addFields:{“doc.services”:”$services”}}` between your group and replaceRoot stage. Is that what you are asking ?

Comment: I've updated the question, `services` schema has more properties, not only services. I want to keep them too after the aggregation. I could `$group` everything with `$first` and in the next stage `$project` them but i have five more `refs` that i need to lookup and group using the same code and this needs so much code, they are large objects, I was hoping that there could be an easier way.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t follow you. addFields stage keeps the existing fields while mutating/creating the fields in the stage. For looking up you have to do one a time there is no shortcut. See if you can update the question with more details and I can give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

So you are using mongoose schema but then going down to mongoDB for the aggregations.

You need to use [`populate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population) and it's [`match stage`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions) from `mongoose`.

populate is what would tie in the `refs` for you etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I need to use aggregation because I make more queries before reaching this stage, `aggregate.lookup({})` is using mongoose, I don't quite understand why you are pointing out that I use mongoose and then going down to mongoDB.